# SVG Image load event firing before image is actually loaded

Tags: javascript, image, svg, promise, onload

I have an SVG image that contains `<image>` tags with hrefs to other external images. For an function on this SVG I need to convert these URLs to their dataURL equivalent before exporting. I have the conversion working am having some difficulties waiting for all the URLs to finish converting prior to calling the function.

My code looks something like the following:

```js
// Convert a URL to a dataURL, returns Promise for when it's complete
const convertUrlToDataUrl = (url) => {
  let resolvePromise, rejectPromise;
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolvePromise = resolve;
    rejectPromise = reject;
  });

  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = (event) =>  {
    const loadedImage = event.target;
    const {width, height} = loadedImage;
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(loadedImage, 0, 0);
    const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    resolvePromise(dataUrl);
  };

  img.onerror = () => {
    rejectPromise();
  };
  img.src = url;
  return promise;
};

// Updates a SVG image tags href to a dataURL of the image
const updateImageToDataUrl = async (image) => {
    const url = image.getAttribute('href') || image.getAttribute('xlink:href');
    try {
      dataUrl = await convertUrlToDataUrl(url);
    } catch(e) {
      dataUrl = 'some backup data URL';
    }

    // Update image tag image reference to data URL and create imageUrlUpdated promise to complete when image has loaded
    let resolvePromise, rejectPromise;
    const imageUrlUpdated = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolvePromise = resolve;
      rejectPromise = reject;
    });
    image.addEventListener('load', e => resolvePromise(), {once: true});
    image.addEventListener('error', () => rejectPromise(), {once: true});

    // Update image (both xlink:href and href for backwards compatiablity)
    if (image.hasAttribute('xlink:href')) { image.setAttribute('xlink:href', dataUrl); }
    if (image.hasAttribute('href')) { image.setAttribute('href', dataUrl); }

    // Wait for image to load after updating URL
    try {
        await imageUrlUpdated;
        console.log('Image fully updated');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Something went wrong');
    }
};

// Get all svg image elements to change
const svgImages = getSVGImageElements();

// Start URL conversion process for each image and store promise of each
const imageUpdatingPromises = [];
svgImages.forEach(image => {
  imageUpdatingPromises.push(updateImageToDataUrl(image));
});

// Wait for all images to be loaded
await Promise.allSettled(imageUpdatingPromises);
  
console.log('Starting doStuffWithSVG');
doStuffWithSVG();
```

The intended behaviour of the above code is to wait until all the SVG image tags have been updated with data URLS before calling `doStuffWithSVG();`. Upon testing it appears that `doStuffWithSVG()` is running before all the images have updated (I say this as I am getting an error that occurs when using an external URL instead of a data URL for my particular use case).

While trying to debug this all the logs `"Image fully updated"` happen before the log `"Starting doStuffWithSVG"` and `"Something went wrong"` is never called which indcates that my promises all do seem to be running in the right order and waiting appropriately. I can confirm that the actual `href` and `xlink:href` attributes on the image tag are all data URLs by the time `doStuffWithSVG` is called but I am still getting an error. In addition when calling this code in succession it will work after the first time, my guess for why is that the images are cached so the actual images update faster the subsequent runs.

I should mention that I am only seeing this issue in Safari (I am still seeing all the same expected logging in Safari though) but I am not convinced it is a browser specific issue but that the safari javascript engine is just slower and is why I am seeing it here (Can confirm that compared to chrome or firefox, Safari takes much longer to convert the images to data URLs). The reason I think this is that I have not been able to find any other differences in what is getting called or in what order between the browsers besides speed (Safari still uses `xlink:href` instead of `href` but that doesn't seem to be making a difference here).

With everything above it seems to me like the `load` event is firing on the `SVGImageElements` before the actual image has loaded. That or I have made a mistake in setting up and awaiting my Promises somewhere. Any help on this would be great as I have run out of ideas of how else I can accomplish this or what else the problem could be.

Comment: JS programming note: instead of allocating an array and then filling it through forEach, then resolving all the Promises, you want `await Promise.allSettled(svgImages.map(updateImageToDataUrl))`. And you _definitely_ want that `await` in there because allSettled _itself_ is a Promise, too.

Comment: In a browser that still doesn't support the svg `href` attribute you'd need to set the `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` namespace to both `getAttributeNS` and `setAttributeNS`. Also, the load event of SVGImageElement used to be called `SVGLoad`, and it never was truly well supported cross-browser. Why do you need to wait for that event? Can't you stay with HTMLImageElement instead (or even better with ImageBitmaps)?

Comment: @Kaiido I just tested and it looks like `setAttribute('xlink:href', blah)` is working in my version of safari at least so I don't think that is the issue but I will update to use the `NS` methods for better support.

With the current load the `load` event is firing but I will try the `SVGLoad` event to see if that fixes it. 

Finally I added the logic for waiting on `SVGImageElement.load` event to try and fix my problem (it didn't) so it may actually not be necessary here. I am updating an `<image>` tag though and think this is the event fired when that completes.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe any of my points were related to your issue, just that your code was assuming it handled legacy browsers, when it doesn't. I still don't understand "why" you are waiting for the <image> to be loaded though. What are you doing with this SVG <image> that requires it to be loaded? The only API I can think of where this would be needed would be to draw that <image> to a canvas, but for this you shouldn't need the <image> at all, just use the <img> you built (and Safari still doesn't support drawing <image> on canvas anyway).